# Is there a consensus on whether or not newly defined utility functions should be partial?

Tags: haskell

For example, many functions in `Data.List` are partial, such as `(cycle, (!!), init, tail, head, last)`. I'm currently writing a module which defines a type similar to lists, namely, infinite lists. This of course avoids certain partiality problems, but doesn't solve, for example, `cycle`.

The dilemma I'm faced with now is the following:
Do I implement a safer version of `cycle :: [a] -> Maybe (InfList a)`,
or do I implement a more useful, less safe, more `base`-like function?

Is there any consensus on this?

Comment: Surely it depends on what you want to achieve? If you think having a total function would make your code better, go for it.

Comment: I think it depends on who you're expecting to use the library and what for? Though consensus seems to favour total functions. How about `NonEmpty a -> InfList a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no general convention for this. You may provide both versions to let user choose who is responsible for handling possible errors caused by out-of-domain arguments.

Take a look at [list to non-empty list conversion](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.8/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html#v:fromList). The author provides two constructing functions: `fromList` that assumes the list on input is non-empty, and `nonEmpty` that returns `Maybe`. In your case I would name them for example `fromCycle` and `cyclicInfList` respectively to match that convention.

Sometimes it is hard to tell which implementation will be more accurate. In some cases the user may like to have control over it, but sometimes he is sure that argument is correct which would lead to abominations like use of `fromJust` (gross). In my opinion the most diplomatic way is to provide both definitions and move your dilemma to the next programmer.

Comment: What's so incredibly gross about fromJust?

Comment: Expecting `fromJust` to succeed implies that `Maybe` wasn't necessary in the first place. The purpose of `Maybe` is to encode the possibility of failure, and `fromJust` (which is equivalent to `fromMaybe undefined`) just sweeps that possibility under the rug.

Comment: Exactly. It is useful when you want to test some code that you are sure will return `Just`, but when I see it on production I am always suspicious whether it is conceptually proper. I saw once project where `fromJust` was banned and one had to use `fromJustNote :: String -> Maybe a -> a` that required justification of its use